# Apache in Mountain Lion

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to set up Apache in Mountain Lion, and am confused about something. If I go to localhost it says "It works!", but thats as far as I can get. There are many tutorials on how to put your website under localhost/~USERNAME, but that seems annoying. What would I need to do to get the website under localhost instead of localhost/~USERNAME ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the standard Apache config with

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

There you can change the standard document root from

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

to whatever you may please and ignore the user specific sites  in ~/Sites
Do not forget to restart the server after you have made config changes.

Comment: Hey! Figured out where the root is now! Thank you! :D